# Error reading /Applications/Xcode. The file doesn’t exist

Tags: macos, xcode

I have installed Xcode 6.2 in 10.9.5, and i dont know why, when i run,

```
xcodebuild -license
```

i get this error message,

```
Error reading /Applications/Xcode.  The file doesn’t exist.


By typing 'agree' you are agreeing to the terms of the software license agreements. Type 'print' to print them or anything else to cancel, [agree, print, cancel] agree

You can view the license agreements in Xcode's About Box, or at /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf
```

After this i notice that xcodebuild is not well pointed, because 'xcode' folder doesnt exist, i just have 'xcode 2.app', so i dont know if i will have problems in the future, since i am getting this error, and if yes how can i fix it?

Comment: Xcode shouldn't have a space in its name, that's why it only searches for /Applications/Xcode.

Comment: I have already reported this to apple, but i dont believe that they will do anything because i am working with old versions.

Comment: it's not a bug. It's how the command line works. If you want to copy a file, you use `cp /path/file /path/copy`. You use spaces to signal a new argument. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. It's how the command line works. If you want to copy a file, you use `cp /path/file /path/copy`. You use spaces to signal a new argument. If you have spaces in your path, you must tell bash to ignore them: `cp /path\ with\ spaces/file /path/copy`.

If you use `brew`, they have a notice on their website that says that Xcode must not have spaces in the name, otherwise the Xcode command line tools won't work properly. (Brew link: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/38049 )

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible this is due to the location of the xcodetools?

Go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations and select the command line tools from the right location.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a real answer but it seems that there is a bug from apple here, so i have reported to them, this issue.

It shouldnt be a space between 'xcode' and '2'.

Comment: Hmm, there shouldn't be a space **and** a 2. Usually the `somename 2` is the result of some user/Finder interaction to avoid overwriting/replacing the original file/folder/app bundle